# Keyboard shortcut to switch between source and test files easily

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, moreunit

Is there an extension or a keyboard shortcut like MoreUnit for Eclipse in Visual Studio that would allow me to quick switch between a source file and a unit testing file.

Also in Eclipse, I used to create a file (test or source) and then hit `CTRL+J` and it would suggest me to create to opposite file and then allow me to switch between them with `CTRL+J`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if there is an extension like this one for eclipse. Normally I use `Ctrl` + `Tab` to switch between the current file and the last one. Of course this works only when I open the test file first and then the implementation, but I usually work that way.

I guess this could be an idea for a new extension.

Comment: For those of us that are not German, a quick Google search tells me that `Strg` is `CTRL`.

Comment: @cadrell0 ufff, sorry :-) Sometimes such things happen.

Comment: I use Ctrl-Tab to swap between one or more files at a time. A single Ctrl-Tab gets you to the next-most-recent file, so toggling between two files repeatedly is fairly easy.

Answer (score 0):

Install TestDriven.NET in Visual Studio and you've this great shortcut **Alt+G** to do exactly that. Additionally an equivalent option shows up in the editor's context menu.

You can download TestDriven.Net on http://www.testdriven.net/download.aspx or http://www.heise.de/download/testdriven.net-1149771.html.